# kubernetes loadbalancer with multiple backend ports

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have an application with three different backend types. Each of them is listening on different ports (eg 8080, 8180, 8280).
Now I would like to access them by using `http://example.com:{8080,8180,8280}`. To be safe there should be running two pods of each service.

1. How should the yaml file look like with multiple backends, each of them having a different port?
2. Can I include the definition for replicas in the same file? Or is there some kind of main file in kubernetes where I can include other files?

Answer (score 0):

To do this you would create multiple services, see http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/ for details.

An example could look like (using yaml, you can also use json):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: yourservice_1
  namespace: default
  labels:
    component: yourcomponent
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    component: yourcomponent
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: yourservice_2
  namespace: default
  labels:
    component: yourcomponent
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    component: yourcomponent
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8081
    protocol: TCP
---
Etc.
```

And to answer the second part of your question:

The **---** is to have multiple definitions (can be services, can be any kubernetes yaml), in a single file.

I however advice a separate file for services since they in general tend to be loaded just once, and a separate file for your pod definitions (since that will change more often).

One thing to be aware of with the multiple service definition: In (at least Kubernetes 1.3.5/1.3.6, versions which I am using), there is a runaway pod issue in which certain combinations of selectors lead to kubernetes starting just as many pods as it can. To prevent this: Test and experiment. It does work as long as you avoid this condition.

A single service entry point can be also be used and can be defined as:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: yourservice_1
  namespace: default
  labels:
    component: yourcomponent
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    component: yourcomponent
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 8080
    protocol: TCP
  - name: http2
    port: 8081
    protocol: TCP
  - name: http2
    port: 8082
    protocol: TCP
```

Comment: How do you get a single entry point for all these services? As the original question stated: `http://example.com`...

Comment: Ah, understood your question different. See part 2 of the answer.

Comment: Can services point to other services? AFAIK, they need to point to pods. If you are using load-balancer services, each services would get its own IP - so you can't have example.com:81 pointing to the pods in the deployment http on port 80 and example.com:1883 pointing to the deployment mqtt on port 1883? (With NodePort maybe, but then you need to manually configure a load-balancer to point to the nodes (which might change dynamically...))

Comment: @GertvandenBerg The scenario you describe (as I understand your description), is the ingress: An ingress points to multiple services and can thus organize the application

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen Except that an Ingress only supports HTTP services (and only on port 80 and 443), unless you are using controller-specific extensions (Such as Voyager's non-standard Ingress resource and the nginx-ingress and ingress-nginx's (differently formatted) configmaps), which limits portability - it adds a dependency on a specific ingress controller...

Comment: @GertvandenBerg Agreed. We need a diagramming tool to get your first idea clear: SVC -> SVC(s) as in composition of services to get a single address. I do not know enough about service mesh networks (istio and the likes) to know if they could address this style of composition in a more elegant style than with an ingress.